How to: local traffic through ibss network, www through a managed network
I have several local computers in a simple home setup, the interfaces all configured with systemd-networkd (systemd version 252), all running in debian bookworm (12.7).
Each computer has a wifi dongle to connect to the local network, and either built-in wifi or ethernet to connect to a dsl router (which is the access point for the non-local wifi network).
I wish to have the local network use ipv6 link-local addressing exclusively and not go through the dsl router.
Setting up the non-local network is easy and uses the systemd dhcp facility and wpa-supplicant-nl80211@interface.service.
Can anyone suggest how to write the local.network file? Such that one local machine talking to the next is a simple point-to-point connection over the ibss network.

Write an empty .network file that only [Match]-es the interface (causing networkd to bring it up, if it is not already admin-up) and does nothing else.
All broadcast interfaces automatically have IPv6 link-local addresses, so no address configuration is needed; and since the socket API already requires you to specify an output interface when sending packets to a link-local address (on Linux, anyway), no routing configuration is needed.
But to point out: There is nothing that actually requires the use of IPv6 link-local addresses here. Same-subnet IP communications already are link-local by definition and never go through the router, just by nature of being "same-subnet".
In other words, as long as two hosts have their (connected) interfaces configured with addresses within the same subnet, they will automatically get "local subnet" routes to each other – which are more-specific and thus have higher priority than the "default gateway via DSL" route – and all communication between those IP addresses will naturally use that direct connection.
This is how IPv6 link-local addresses are implemented on Linux, but it applies equally to any IP version and any address scope. So you could achieve the same goal (of direct communications through the dedicated link) by configuring e.g. common Address=192.168.5.x/24 (IPv4 private) or Address=fd01::xxx/64 (IPv6 ULA) on both machines.
Running ip route get 192.168.5.y [fibmatch] would then show that the peer's address is routed through the dedicated interface. This method will likely cause less problems than trying to use IPv6 link-local addresses (as there are still programs that fail to parse them or lose the zone index field).

So far @grawity answer works best of anything I've tried. I did add a [Network] section with "LLMNR=yes". Still testing, I'll mark it solved soon.
